# how can I tell if two strings have a common character section?--Python

Tags: python

there are two strings:

```
   str1 = "black_red_yellow"

   str2 = "blue_red_green"
```

which python library can I use to check these two strings have a substring`"_red_"` in common? thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this need to work on arbitrary things or is str1 always a substring of str2?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2892931/1025391

Comment: In this simple case, `str1 in str2` will evaluate to `True`

Comment: is this section always delimited by "_" characters as in your example?

Comment: hi all, sorry just updated the question, "_" is not necessary always in the string, can be any characters. The question is how to check if: str1 has something that can be found in str2. thanks.

Comment: are you looking for longest common substring? or first common string longer than 1 char? or common words? Last is really easy... Or perhaps a list of substring such that eash `sub in s1 and sub in s2`?

Comment: yes qarma, you are right, I was actually looking for the longest common substring rather than others, so if a condition check that can find both strings have a substring "_red_" in common should return "true". moooeeeep 's comments might help a bit to my question. Sorry all for the ambiguity in the question.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I can check the substring(any length) only following a specific character, for example "id": str1= " black_id_red_yellow", str2="blue_id_red_green",so because "red" is found after "id_" in both, the algorithm should return "true".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work if you don't know the actual string you're searching for

```
import difflib

str1 = "black_red_yellow"
str2 = "blue_red_green"

difference = difflib.SequenceMatcher()

difference.set_seqs(str1, str2)

for match in difference.get_matching_blocks():
    print str1[match[0]:match[0] + match[2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

1. test for presence of common substring, including length 1:

```
    if set(str1).intersection(set(str2)): print "yes we can!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) to compare strings in that way.  However, if you know the string you're looking for you could just do `'_red_' in str1 and '_red_' in str2`.  If you don't know the string, then do you look for a specific length of match?  E.g. would `'red'` match `'blue'` because they both contain `'e'`?  The shortest, simplest way of checking for any match at all would be

```
bool([a for a in str1 if a in str2])
```

**Edit:** Or, more efficiently,

```
any(a for a in str1 if a in str2)
```

Comment: `any(a for a in str1 if a in str2)` might be more efficient

Comment: I didn't think it would be any different, but it turns out to be more than twice as fast!  I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't find anything else, then there's at least this naive implementation:

```
str1 = "black_red_yellow"
str2 = "blue_red_green"

if len(str1) < len(str2):
    min_str = str1
    max_str = str2
else:
    min_str = str2
    max_str = str1

matches = []
min_len = len(min_str)
for b in xrange(min_len):
    for e in xrange(min_len, b, -1):
        chunk = min_str[b:e]
        if chunk in max_str:
            matches.append(chunk)

print max(matches, key=len)
```

prints `_red_`

Comment: it is O(n^2), where n is min(len(str1), len(str2))