# how to intersect lists in python with respect to index

Tags: python, list

i know this question might look like a duplicate. but i had a hard time trying to solve this and i couldn't find a helpful solution for my case

i'am implementing a genetic algorithm using python for the traveling salesman problem

assume we have those lists ( tours)

```
a = [1,0,2,5,4,3,1]
b = [1,2,5,4,3,0,1]
c = [1,3,5,4,2,0,1]
```

as you can see, the [5,4] is repeated in the whole 3 lists
and a regular intersection would return all the elements in the list.

i want some function like  intersect_list(a,b)

that returns [5,4]

is there a python built-in way to find this? or do you have any suggestion?.

**Note** : i know i can loop it to solve this , but please put in mind that in my case i have around 400 lists. and at the length of 401 each.

in other words : i want to see the common path between those lists.

please let me know if anything was unclear
thanks in advance.

Comment: So, to clarify, you want any runs of two or more items that are in the same order in both lists?

Comment: Are all lists in the input permutations of one another?

Comment: Why shouldn't `intersect_list(a,b)` return `[2,5,4,3]` ?

Comment: Feels like a longest-common-contiguous-subsequence problem to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After taking a look at the links posted by @pyfunc, I came up with the following:

```
def shortest_of(lists):
    return min(lists, key=len)

def contains_sublist(lst, sublst):
    n = len(sublst)
    return any((sublst == lst[i:i+n]) for i in xrange(len(lst)-n+1)) 

def longest_common(lists):
    if not lists:
        return ()
    res = set()    
    base = shortest_of(lists)
    length = len(base)

    for i in xrange(length, 0, -1):
        for j in xrange(length - i + 1):
            candidate = ', ' + str(base[j:i+j]).strip('[]') + ','
            #candidate = base[j:i+j]  

            for alist in lists:
                if not candidate in ', ' + str(alist).strip('[]') + ',':
                #if not contains_sublist(alist, candidate):   
                    break
            else:
                res.add(tuple([int(a) for a in candidate[2:-1].split(',')]))
                #res.add(tuple(candidate))

        if res:
            return tuple(res)    

    return ()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1,0,2,5,4,3,1]
    b = [1,2,5,4,3,0,1]
    c = [1,3,5,4,2,0,1]

    print longest_common([a,b,c])
    print longest_common([b,c])
```

output:

```
((5, 4),)
((0, 1), (5, 4))
```

#### EDIT:

Updated solution to use string conversions and matching as it happened to be way faster. Previous solution parts are commented out. Also, it now gives all possibilities.

Comment: nice, checking from large to small and not doing all the work up front (as i did), makes it way quicker :)

Comment: Yes, but I think mine would be slower if the largest common sublist contains very few elements. I'm not good at benchmarking, so I haven't tried.

Comment: @Amr: good to see that you worked it out and posted your answer back

Answer (score 1):

One idea is that you can convert your list into a string with

```
",".join(list)
```

and then the problem is transformed to longest matching substring in two strings.

Solution and discussion for that is there on SO at :

1. [Longest common substring from more than two strings - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python)
2. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#Python

Comment: Why convert to strings? The algorithm for longest substring would work for lists the same way

Comment: @JBernardo: Yes, I was thinking along largest substring and hence the answer. I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

400 lists of length 400 isn't too much of a problem. First break each sequence into all its possible subsequences, (a list of length `N` has around `0.5 * N ** 2` possible subsequences). Then intersect them all and take the longest one.

```
a = [1,0,2,5,4,3,1]
b = [1,2,5,4,3,0,1]
c = [1,3,5,4,2,0,1]

def longest_match_finder(lists):
    matches = []
    for a in lists:
        lengths = set()
        for leng in xrange(1,len(a)+1):
            lengths = lengths | set(tuple(a[i:i+leng]) 
                                    for i in xrange(len(a)-leng+1))
        matches.append(lengths)
    return max(set.intersection(*matches), key=len)

print longest_match_finder([a,b,c])
#Output:
(5, 4)
```

With `400` lists each with `400` elements, this takes around `280 seconds` (on my very old machine). However if we use the same approach on just one list, but convert its sub-sequences and also all the others lists to strings (as first posted by @pyfunc), using `str(list).strip('[]')`, we can search much quicker. The same test runs in `21 seconds`:

```
import ast

def longest_match_finder_2(lists):
    a = lists[0]
    lengths = set()
    for leng in xrange(1,len(a)+1):
        lengths = lengths | set(str(a[i:i+leng]).strip('[]') 
                                for i in xrange(len(a)-leng+1))
    for seq in lengths.copy():
        if not all([seq in str(i).strip('[]') for i in lists[1:]]):
            lengths.remove(seq)
    return ast.literal_eval(max(lengths, key=len))
```

We can use `ast.literal_eval()` to get a list back (safely) at the end.

Comment: There's a problem, try `longest_match_finder([a,b])`, the output is `(5,4,3)` while it should be `(2,5,4,3)`

Comment: @Amr - Thanks, fixed it. Stupidly taking max on magnitude not length!

Comment: I updated my code my code to use strings too. there's a little problem     though, eg: `[1,2,3]` would be `'1 , 2, 3'` which would match `[11,2,3]` `'11, 2, 3'`. I fell for it too :)

Comment: @Amr - yeah, i noticed that, just as i realised i was far too tired, and should go to bed :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the list [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) function to zip them into tuples and return the tuples where all the elements are the same.

```
a = [1,0,2,5,4,3,1]
b = [1,2,5,4,3,0,1]
c = [1,3,5,4,2,0,1]
zipped_tuples = zip(a, b, c)
```

You can try to leverage this to get the positional intersections.

Comment: This won't work, as the indices for the subsequences are not necessarily the same.