# Find list of common parent path strings in a list of path strings using python

Tags: python, filesystems

What is the most effective way to find a list of longest common parent path strings in a list of path strings using python?

*Additional Note* Where there are two or more matches I would like to descend as necessary to create as few as possible redundant

**Input list**

```
input_paths = [
  '/project/path/to/a/directory/of/files',
  '/project/path/to/a/directory/full/of/files',
  '/project/path/to/some/more/files',
  '/project/path/to/some/more/directories/of/files'
  '/project/path/to/another/file',
  '/project/mount/another/path/of/files',
  '/project/mount/another/path/of/test/stuff',
  '/project/mount/another/path/of/files/etc',
  '/project/mount/another/drive/of/things',
  '/project/local/folder/of/documents'
]
filter_path = '/project'
```

**Output list**

```
common_prefix_list = [
  'path/to/a/directory',
  'path/to/some/more',
  'path/to/another',
  'mount/another/path/of',
  'mount/another/drive/of',
  'local/folder/of'
]
```

My rudimentary guess is to split into lists on os.sep and then use set intersection but I believe there are more robust algorithms to find what is essentially a longest common substring problem. I'm sure this has been done a million times before so please offer up your elegant solution.

*My end task is to collect a list of assets common to a project in disparate paths into one common folder with a structure that does not create conflicts with individual assets nor create paths that are overly redundant (hence the `filter_path`).*

Comment: Why these three? Why not `/path/to` for all five inputs?

Comment: A list of all common parents is the same as the list of paths (or their parents). Your problem would make more sense if it were just one result - `/path/to`.

Comment: Continuing @TimPietzcker and @minitech: Consider the trade-off between "*longest* paths" and *shortest* output list (which will yield a list with one element: `/path/to`). These are two different problems. Also, your end task description is not clear to me.

Comment: See [longest common substring from more than two strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python)

Comment: I've seen that post and it's similar but I would still need to pre or post process the list and not sure if there isn't a better way

Comment: @Lior: to be perfectly accurate I should have asked for cases where there are two or more common path prefixes

Comment: `os.path` provides a `commonprefix` function which might be useful for a portion of this problem.  As others have stated, This algorithm needs to be hashed out a little more before we can come up with an implemenatation however.

Comment: @mgilson: I agree - upon further thought there's an element of user input required to determine if the destination path created as a result of culling the common prefix is actually user-friendly - I suppose my goal is to make that input as minimal as possible

Comment: @mgilson: funny thing about commonprefix is this little documentation note: "Note that this may return invalid paths because it works a character at a time." so it's no different than using the string solution suggested [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python)

Comment: @mogga -- Yep, but it's in the standard library, so you don't need to roll your own version :)

Comment: Should `'/mount/another/drive/of/'` be one of the returned results, or is the inclusion of `'/path/to/another'` incorrect?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor just said what I spotted as well: the output is wrong. That's because the problem is ill-defined. How many folder should be retained, in general?
There is one answer only that is clear, namely to find *the* common ancestor (which, in your case, is "/"). Please update your question, otherwise it doesn't constitute a valid question.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor fixed the output... 10 years later...