# Match a running ipython notebook to a process

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

My server runs many long running notebooks, and I'd like to monitor the notebooks memory.

Is there a way to match between the pid or process name and a notebook?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the question is about monitoring notebooks' memory, I've written a complete example showing the memory consumption of the running notebooks. It is based on the excellent @jcb91 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29113651/304209) and a few other answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44712205/304209), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30014612/304209), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2894073/304209), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266225/304209)).

```python
import json
import os
import os.path
import posixpath
import subprocess
import urllib2

import pandas as pd
import psutil


def show_notebooks_table(host, port):
    """Show table with info about running jupyter notebooks.

    Args:
        host: host of the jupyter server.
        port: port of the jupyter server.

    Returns:
        DataFrame with rows corresponding to running notebooks and following columns:
            * index: notebook kernel id.
            * path: path to notebook file.
            * pid: pid of the notebook process.
            * memory: notebook memory consumption in percentage.
    """
    notebooks = get_running_notebooks(host, port)
    prefix = long_substr([notebook['path'] for notebook in notebooks])
    df = pd.DataFrame(notebooks)
    df = df.set_index('kernel_id')
    df.index.name = prefix
    df.path = df.path.apply(lambda x: x[len(prefix):])
    df['pid'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_process_id(row.name), axis=1)
    # same notebook can be run in multiple processes
    df = expand_column(df, 'pid')
    df['memory'] = df.pid.apply(memory_usage_psutil)
    return df.sort_values('memory', ascending=False)


def get_running_notebooks(host, port):
    """Get kernel ids and paths of the running notebooks.

    Args:
        host: host at which the notebook server is listening. E.g. 'localhost'.
        port: port at which the notebook server is listening. E.g. 8888.
        username: name of the user who runs the notebooks.

    Returns:
        list of dicts {kernel_id: notebook kernel id, path: path to notebook file}.
    """
    # find which kernel corresponds to which notebook
    # by querying the notebook server api for sessions
    sessions_url = posixpath.join('http://%s:%d' % (host, port), 'api', 'sessions')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(sessions_url).read()
    res = json.loads(response)
    notebooks = [{'kernel_id': notebook['kernel']['id'],
                  'path': notebook['notebook']['path']} for notebook in res]
    return notebooks


def get_process_id(name):
    """Return process ids found by (partial) name or regex.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44712205/304209.
    >>> get_process_id('kthreadd')
    [2]
    >>> get_process_id('watchdog')
    [10, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56, 61]  # ymmv
    >>> get_process_id('non-existent process')
    []
    """
    child = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', '-f', name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    response = child.communicate()[0]
    return [int(pid) for pid in response.split()]


def memory_usage_psutil(pid=None):
    """Get memory usage percentage by current process or by process specified by id, like in top.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30014612/304209.

    Args:
        pid: pid of the process to analyze. If None, analyze the current process.

    Returns:
        memory usage of the process, in percentage like in top, values in [0, 100].
    """
    if pid is None:
        pid = os.getpid()
    process = psutil.Process(pid)
    return process.memory_percent()


def long_substr(strings):
    """Find longest common substring in a list of strings.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2894073/304209.

    Args:
        strings: list of strings.

    Returns:
        longest substring which is found in all of the strings.
    """
    substr = ''
    if len(strings) > 1 and len(strings[0]) > 0:
        for i in range(len(strings[0])):
            for j in range(len(strings[0])-i+1):
                if j > len(substr) and all(strings[0][i:i+j] in x for x in strings):
                    substr = strings[0][i:i+j]
    return substr


def expand_column(dataframe, column):
    """Transform iterable column values into multiple rows.

    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266225/304209.

    Args:
        dataframe: DataFrame to process.
        column: name of the column to expand.

    Returns:
        copy of the DataFrame with the following updates:
            * for rows where column contains only 1 value, keep them as is.
            * for rows where column contains a list of values, transform them
                into multiple rows, each of which contains one value from the list in column.
    """
    tmp_df = dataframe.apply(
        lambda row: pd.Series(row[column]), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
    tmp_df.name = column
    return dataframe.drop(column, axis=1).join(tmp_df)
```

Here is an example output of `show_notebooks_table('localhost', 8888)`:

[image: example output of show_notebooks_table]

Comment: very nice! one small correction that I had to do, my notebooks don't have a common prefix, so the function `long_substr` returned `.ipynb`, so I removed that past since it just truncated 6 chars from each start of a path

Comment: thank you for accepting the answer! Feel free to update the code in it so that it works in your case too.

Comment: With `python3`, after substituting `urllib.request` for `urllib2`, I am getting a 403 error at this line:  `response = urllib.request.urlopen(sessions_url).read()`....

Comment: @Him I think the issue is authorization - jupyter has increased the security and now you need to add an authorization header like token or password. Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/2torus/dbeb47b81eb18f2baf20bff6adf7b805 that prompts you for a token and then adds it to request headers.

Answer (score 10):

I came here looking for the simple answer to this question, so I'll post it for anyone else looking.

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

Comment: Brilliant in its simplicity!

Answer (score 6):

This is possible, although I could only think of the rather hackish solution I outline below. In summary:

1. Get the ports each kernel (id) is listening on from the corresponding json connection files residing in the server's `security` directory
2. Parse the output of a call to `netstat` to determine which pid is listening to the ports found in step 1
3. Query the server's sessions url to find which kernel id maps to which session, and hence to which notebook. See [the ipython  wiki for the api](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Dev:-URL-mapping-of-IPython-notebook). Although not all of it works for me, running IPython 2.1.0, the sessions url does.

I suspect there is a much simpler way, but I'm not sure as yet where to find it.

```python
import glob
import os.path
import posixpath
import re
import json
import subprocess
import urllib2

# the url and port at which your notebook server listens
server_path = 'http://localhost'
server_port = 8888
# the security directory of the notebook server, containing its connections files
server_sec_dir = 'C:/Users/Josh/.ipython/profile_default/security/'

# part 1 : open all the connection json files to find their port numbers
kernels = {}
for json_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(server_sec_dir, 'kernel-*.json')):
    control_port = json.load(open(json_path, 'r'))['control_port']
    key = os.path.basename(json_path)[7:-5]
    kernels[control_port] = {'control_port': control_port, 'key': key}

# part2 : get netstat info for which processes use which tcp ports
netstat_ouput = subprocess.check_output(['netstat', '-ano'])
# parse the netstat output to map ports to PIDs
netstat_regex = re.compile(
    "^\s+\w+\s+" # protocol word
    "\d+(\.\d+){3}:(\d+)\s+" # local ip:port
    "\d+(\.\d+){3}:(\d+)\s+" # foreign ip:port 
    "LISTENING\s+" # connection state
    "(\d+)$" # PID
)
for line in netstat_ouput.splitlines(False):
    match = netstat_regex.match(line)
    if match and match.lastindex == 5:
        port = int(match.group(2))
        if port in kernels:
            pid = int(match.group(5))
            kernels[port]['pid'] = pid

# reorganize kernels to use 'key' as keys
kernels = {kernel['key']: kernel for kernel in kernels.values()}

# part 3 : find which kernel corresponds to which notebook
# by querying the notebook server api for sessions
sessions_url = posixpath.join('%s:%d' % (server_path, server_port),
                              'api','sessions')
response = urllib2.urlopen(sessions_url).read()
for session in json.loads(response):
    key = session['kernel']['id']
    if key in kernels:
        nb_path = os.path.join(session['notebook']['path'],
                               session['notebook']['name'])
        kernels[key]['nb_path'] = nb_path

# now do what you will with the dict. I just print a pretty list version:
print json.dumps(kernels.values(), sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

outputs (for me, at the moment):

```
[
    {
        "key": "9142896a-34ca-4c01-bc71-e5709652cac5",
        "nb_path": "2015/2015-01-16\\serhsdh.ipynb",
        "pid": 11436,
        "port": 56173
    },
    {
        "key": "1ddedd95-5673-45a6-b0fb-a3083debb681",
        "nb_path": "Untitled0.ipynb",
        "pid": 11248,
        "port": 52191
    },
    {
        "key": "330343dc-ae60-4f5c-b9b8-e5d05643df19",
        "nb_path": "ipynb\\temp.ipynb",
        "pid": 4680,
        "port": 55446
    },
    {
        "key": "888ad49b-5729-40c8-8d53-0e025b03ecc6",
        "nb_path": "Untitled2.ipynb",
        "pid": 7584,
        "port": 55401
    },
    {
        "key": "26d9ddd2-546a-40b4-975f-07403bb4e048",
        "nb_path": "Untitled1.ipynb",
        "pid": 10916,
        "port": 55351
    }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the Dennis Golomazov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44936664/1661267) to:

- Make the code compatible with Python 3
- Allow to login into a password-protected session

I replaced the get_running_notebooks function by this one ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55568762/1661267)):

```
import requests
import posixpath
import json

def get_running_notebooks(host, port, password=''):
    """
    Get kernel ids and paths of the running notebooks.

    Args:
        host: host at which the notebook server is listening. E.g. 'localhost'.
        port: port at which the notebook server is listening. E.g. 8888.
            
    Returns:
        list of dicts {kernel_id: notebook kernel id, path: path to notebook file}.
    """
        
    BASE_URL = 'http://{0}:{1}/'.format(host, port)
        
    # Get the cookie data
    s = requests.Session()
    url = BASE_URL + 'login?next=%2F'
    resp = s.get(url)
    xsrf_cookie = resp.cookies['_xsrf']

    # Login with the password
    params = {'_xsrf': xsrf_cookie, 'password': password}
    res = s.post(url, data=params)

    # Find which kernel corresponds to which notebook
    # by querying the notebook server api for sessions
    url = posixpath.join(BASE_URL, 'api', 'sessions')
    ret = s.get(url)
    #print('Status code:', ret.status_code)

    # Get the notebook list
    res = json.loads(ret.text)
    notebooks = [{'kernel_id': notebook['kernel']['id'],
                  'path': notebook['notebook']['path']} for notebook in res]
    return notebooks
```

Answer (score 1):

I have asked similar question and in order to make it a duplicate I "reverse engineer" [Dennis Golomazov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44936664/4879688) with focus on matching notebooks in a generic way (also manually).

1. Get json from the `api/sessions` path of your Jupyter server (i.e. https://localhost:8888/api/sessions in most cases).
2. Parse the json.  It is a sequence of session objects (nested `dict`s if parsed with `json` module).  Their `.path` attributes point to the notebook file, and `.kernel.id` is the kernel id (which is a part of path passed as an argument of `python -m ipykernel_launcher`, in my case `{PATH}/python -m ipykernel_launcher -f {HOME}/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-{ID}.json).
3. Find PID of process run with that path (e.g. by `pgrep -f {ID}`).

Comment: I wish I read your answer first before reverse engineering myself the ones above : ) For at-the-moment investigation this is the quickest to obtain answer with least effort. Coming from the other way , i.e. seeing many running notebooks processes in task manager, with one especially memory / cpy hungry and trying to id it -> add 'command line' to task manager what will display kernel ids. Then following #1 from above cross reference kernel id to the path of the notebook.  Looking for bit more info out of jsons, windows path would be c:\Users\<your_user_name>\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that solves the access issue mentioned in other posts by first obtaining the access-token via `jupyter lab list`.

```
import requests
import psutil
import re
import os
import pandas as pd

# get all processes that have a ipython kernel and get kernel id
dfp = pd.DataFrame({'p':  [p for p in psutil.process_iter() if 'ipykernel_launcher' in ' '.join(p.cmdline())]})
dfp['kernel_id'] = dfp.p.apply(lambda p: re.findall(r".+kernel-(.+)\.json", ' '.join(p.cmdline()))[0])

# get url to jupyter server with token and open once to get access
urlp = requests.utils.parse_url([i for i in os.popen("jupyter lab list").read().split() if 'http://' in i][0])
s = requests.Session()
res = s.get(urlp)

# read notebook list into dataframe and get kernel id
resapi = s.get(f'http://{urlp.netloc}/api/sessions')
dfn = pd.DataFrame(resapi.json())
dfn['kernel_id'] = dfn.kernel.apply(lambda item: item['id'])

# merge the process and notebook dataframes
df = dfn.merge(dfp, how = 'inner')

# add process info as desired
df['pid'] = df.p.apply(lambda p: p.pid)
df['mem [%]'] = df.p.apply(lambda p: p.memory_percent())
df['cpu [%]'] = df.p.apply(lambda p: p.cpu_percent())
df['status'] = df.p.apply(lambda p: p.status())

# reduce to columns of interest and sort
dfout = df.loc[:,['name','pid','mem [%]', 'cpu [%]','status']].sort_values('mem [%]', ascending=False)
```