# Pandas DataFrame: create a column from a list inside a column

Tags: python, list, pandas, col

I'm having the pandas DataFrame 'test_df':

```
email                      my_list
email1@email1.com          [1,9,3,5]
email2@email2.com          [6,3,3,15]
email3@email3.com          [7,7,2,5]
email4@email4.com          [5,5,5,5]
```

How can I have this following DataFrame (take the first 2 elem of 'my_list'):

```
email                      col1             col2             
email1@email1.com          1                9        
email2@email2.com          6                3
email3@email3.com          7                7
email4@email4.com          5                5
```

I tried:

```
test_df['col1'] = test_df['my_list'][0]
test_df['col2'] = test_df['my_list'][1]
```

But it's not working

Comment: What is the element type of `my_list`?  IOW, what does `type(test_df.my_list[0])` return?

Comment: thanks for your answer @DSM type(test_df.my_list[0]) <type 'list'>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list), although I wanted to go a bit beyond expanding the lists into columns so the answers are more complicated than what you need. In your case, you can just do:

```
# Using my own example data since it's a bit tough to copy-paste
# a printed table and have the lists show up as lists
df = pd.DataFrame({'email': ['email1@eg.com', 'email2@eg.com'], 
                   'lists': [[1, 9, 3, 5], [6, 3, 3, 15]]})
df
Out[14]: 
           email          lists
0  email1@eg.com   [1, 9, 3, 5]
1  email2@eg.com  [6, 3, 3, 15]

objs = [df, pd.DataFrame(df['lists'].tolist()).iloc[:, :2]]
pd.concat(objs, axis=1).drop('lists', axis=1)
Out[13]: 
           email  0  1
0  email1@eg.com  1  9
1  email2@eg.com  6  3
```

Comment: (also sidenote: it's 'column', not 'colon')