# How to split values which are lists in pandas DataFrame into separate rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data that looks like this DataFrame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['Alice', ['project1', 'project2']],
                       ['Bob', ['project3, project4']]],
                      columns=['employee', 'projects'])
>>> df
    employees    projects
 0  Alice        [project1, project2]
 1  Bob          [project3, project4]
```

(my real data has many columns)

One column contains list values. I need to somehow split each row to separate rows with each of the values in the list, like so:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['Alice', 'project1'], ['Alice', 'project2'],
                       ['Bob', 'project3'], ['Bob', 'project4']],
                      columns=['employee', 'projects'])
>>> df
    employees    projects
 0  Alice        project1
 1  Alice        project2
 2  Bob          project3
 3  Bob          project4
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/32468402/2285236

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012152/how-to-unstack-a-pandas-column-containing-lists-into-multiple-rows ;-)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the duplicate, now I know the term explode