# Python Pandas Create unique dataframe out of many lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I want to create a dataframe that stores a unique variable and its average in every column. Currently I have a dataframe that has 2 columns. One has a list of names while the other has a single value. I want to associate that value with all of the names in the list and eventually find the average value for all the names
This is the data I have:

```
Df1:
names_col                    cost_col
[milk, eggs, cookies]          3
[water, milk, yogurt]          5 
[cookies, diaper, yogurt]      7
```

This is what I want:

```
Df2:
names_col             avg_cost_col
milk                       4
eggs                       3
cookies                    5
water                      5
yogurt                     6
diaper                     7
```

I thought about doing an apply over all the rows somehow or using set() to remove duplicates out of every list but I am not sure. Any help would be appreicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @MaxU's suggestion of vectorized solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012152/unstack-a-pandas-column-containing-lists-into-multiple-rows)

```
ndf = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.repeat(df.cost_col.values, df.names_col.str.len()),
                    'b':np.concatenate(df.names_col.values)})
```

yields

```
    a   b
0   3   milk
1   3   eggs
2   3   cookies
3   5   water
4   5   milk
5   5   yogurt
6   7   cookies
7   7   diaper
8   7   yogurt
```

Then just plain `groupy`+`mean`

```
ndf.groupby('b').mean()

        a
b   
cookies 5
diaper  7
eggs    3
milk    4
water   5
yogurt  6
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC flatten your list (unnest)

```
pd.DataFrame(data=df.cost_col.repeat(df.names_col.str.len()).values,index=np.concatenate(df.names_col.values)).mean(level=0)
Out[221]: 
         0
milk     4
eggs     3
cookies  5
water    5
yogurt   6
diaper   7
```

Answer (score 1):

Set() would be the easiest answer to remove duplicates. 
The notation *list_name extends/unpack your list.

```
l = [["milk", "eggs", "cookies"], 
    ["water", "milk", "yogurt"], 
    ["cookies", "diaper", "yogurt"]]
c = set([*l[0], *l[1], *l[2]])
{'cookies', 'eggs', 'diaper', 'yogurt', 'water', 'milk'}
```

And use it for your pandas columns names. You can convert it back to a list if needed with list()

Comment: This is not an answer to the question the OP want's to use pandas and this doesn't answer the whole question