# How to merge Pandas DataFrame with dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to merge a `df` like this:

```
+------------+----------+
| domain     | username |
+------------+----------+
| @gmail.com | gagaga   |
+------------+----------+
| @mail.com  | bobo     |
+------------+----------+
```

with a dict like this:

```
domain_to_app = {
    '@gmail.com': ['gmail', 'youtube', 'gdrive'],
    '@mail.com': ['email', 'dropbox']
}
```

to get this:

```
+------------+----------+-----------+
| domain     | username | app       |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| @gmail.com | gagaga   | gmail     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| @gmail.com | gagaga   | youtube   |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| @gmail.com | gagaga   | gdrive    |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| @mail.com  | bobo     | email     |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| @mail.com  | bobo     | dropbox   |
+------------+----------+-----------+
```

Is it recommended to convert the `dict` into a `df` with repeating rows and use `merge`, or should i use `map` then [unstack the app column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012152/unstack-a-pandas-column-containing-lists-into-multiple-rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for new `Series` and then `chain.from_iterable` with `repeat` for new `DataFrame`:

```
s = df['domain'].map(domain_to_app)

from itertools import chain

lens = s.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'domain' : df['domain'].values.repeat(lens),
    'username' : df['username'].values.repeat(lens),
     'app' : list(chain.from_iterable(s))
})

print (df)
       domain username      app
0  @gmail.com   gagaga    gmail
1  @gmail.com   gagaga  youtube
2  @gmail.com   gagaga   gdrive
3   @mail.com     bobo    email
4   @mail.com     bobo  dropbox
```

If need repeat multiple columns create `DaatFrame` from `mapped` values, reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and 'repeat' by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df['app'] = df['domain'].map(domain_to_app)

df = (df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('app')
                            .values.tolist())
               .stack()
               .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
               .rename('app'))).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
       domain username      app
0  @gmail.com   gagaga    gmail
1  @gmail.com   gagaga  youtube
2  @gmail.com   gagaga   gdrive
3   @mail.com     bobo    email
4   @mail.com     bobo  dropbox
```

Comment: never knew you could do `s.str.len()` to get the length of each Series item, i have been doing `s.apply(len)` all the while

Comment: `s.apply(len)` is faster by about 10% though

Comment: @iamanigeeit - yes, difference is `.apply(len)` not working with `NaN` :)

Comment: Ahhh ok. I thought `s.str` was only for string operations.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(domain_to_app,orient='index').unstack().reset_index()
result= pd.merge(df1,df2[df2[0].notnull()],left_on=['domain'],right_on=['level_1'])
result=result[['domain','username',0]].rename(columns={0:'app'})
print result
```

Output:

```
       domain username      app
0  @gmail.com   gagaga    gmail
1  @gmail.com   gagaga  youtube
2  @gmail.com   gagaga   gdrive
3   @mail.com     bobo    email
4   @mail.com     bobo  dropbox
```

explanation:

create Dataframe from you dictionary, perform `pd.merge` then clean the dataframe as it requires.