# Convert data frame to another data frame, split compound string cell into individual rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I am looking to convert data frame df1 to df2 using Python. I have a solution that uses loops but I am wondering if there is an easier way to create df2.

df1

```
   Test1   Test2   2014  2015  2016  Present
1     x        a     90    85    84        0
2     x      a:b     88    79    72        1
3     y    a:b:c     75    76    81        0
4     y        b     60    62    66        0
5     y        c     68    62    66        1
```

df2

```
   Test1  Test2   2014  2015  2016  Present
1     x       a     90    85    84        0
2     x       a     88    79    72        1
3     x       b     88    79    72        1
4     y       a     75    76    81        0
5     y       b     75    76    81        0
6     y       c     75    76    81        0
7     y       b     60    62    66        0
8     y       c     68    62    66        1
```

Comment: Interesting question. However, please pick either R or Python as to what answer(s) you want for this question (eg: remove one of the tags). If you want to ask another for the other one - that's great. (It just gets awkward for others to find such techniques later when they're both combined into one).

Comment: (It'd also help for your chosen language if you include your current solution)

Comment: Check `separate_rows` function from `tidyr`

Comment: Thanks. I changed the tags to Python.

Comment: Did it work? I am seeing only python tag now.

Comment: @arqchicago it's reopened but it'd still be a great help if you include your existing solution you're not happy with please.

Comment: also of [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `numpy.repeat` and `itertools.chain`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

# split by delimiter and calculate length for each row
split = df['Test2'].str.split(':')
lens = split.map(len)

# repeat non-split columns
cols = ('Test1', '2014', '2015', '2016', 'Present')
d1 = {col: np.repeat(df[col], lens) for col in cols}

# chain split columns
d2 = {'Test2': list(chain.from_iterable(split))}

# combine in a single dataframe
res = pd.DataFrame({**d1, **d2})

print(res)

   2014  2015  2016  Present Test1 Test2
1    90    85    84        0     x     a
2    88    79    72        1     x     a
2    88    79    72        1     x     b
3    75    76    81        0     y     a
3    75    76    81        0     y     b
3    75    76    81        0     y     c
4    60    62    66        0     y     b
5    68    62    66        1     y     c
```

Answer (score 0):

This will achieve what you want:

```
# Converting "Test2" strings into lists of values
df["Test2"] = df["Test2"].apply(lambda x: x.split(":"))

# Creating second dataframe with "Test2" values
test2 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Test2']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
test2.name = 'Test2'

# Joining both dataframes
df = df.drop('Test2', axis=1).join(test2)
```

```
print(df)

  Test1 2014 2015 2016 Present Test2
1     x   90   85   84       0     a
2     x   88   79   72       1     a
2     x   88   79   72       1     b
3     y   75   76   81       0     a
3     y   75   76   81       0     b
3     y   75   76   81       0     c
4     y   60   62   66       0     b
5     y   68   62   66       1     c
```

---

<sup>Similar questions (column already existing as a list): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43859357/pandas-df-has-one-column-with-lists-how-repeat-rows-with-each-value-of-this-lis)</sup>