# Pandas - aggregate over inconsistent values types (string vs list)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given the following DataFrame, I try to aggregate over columns `'A'` and `'C'`. for `'A'`, count unique appearances of the strings, and for `'C'`, sum the values.

Problem arises when some of the samples in `'A'` are actually lists of those strings.

Here's a simplified example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
               'A' : ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', ['b', 'c', 'd'], 'a', 'a', ['a', 'b', 'c']],
               'C' : [1, 2, 15, 5, 13, 6, 7, 1]})
df
Out[100]: 
   ID          A   C
0   1          a   1
1   1          a   2
2   1          a  15
3   1          b   5
4   1  [b, c, d]  13
5   2          a   6
6   2          a   7
7   2  [a, b, c]   1

aggs = {'A' : lambda x: x.nunique(dropna=True),
        'C' : 'sum'}

# This will result an error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
agg_df = df.groupby('ID').agg(aggs)
```

I'd like the following output:

```
print(agg_df)
    A   C
ID       
1   4  36
2   3  14
```

Which resulted because for `'ID' = 1` we had `'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd`' and for `'ID' = 2`, we had `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

Comment: Does `lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series).stack().nunique()` do it?

Comment: @JonClements Yes it does! put it as an answer so I can kiss you, also if you explain the details in this lambda, I'd appreciate it very much

Comment: `apply(pd.Series)` + `stack` will work but will also likely be very slow.

Comment: @jpp indeed... which is why I haven't posted an answer with it... there *must* be a better pandas-style way of doing it these days... :)

Comment: @JonClements, Yeh it's *such* a common question. My favourite (for small number of columns) is `np.repeat` + `it.chain`, but I feel as though the recipes we repeat should be in-built in Pandas, possibly Cythonised for general use.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to split your problem into 2 parts. First flatten your dataframe to ensure `df['A']` consists only of strings. Then concatenate a couple of `GroupBy` operations.

#### Step 1: Flatten your dataframe

You can use `itertools.chain` and `numpy.repeat` to chain and repeat values as appropriate.

```
from itertools import chain

A = df['A'].apply(lambda x: [x] if not isinstance(x, list) else x)
lens = A.map(len)

res = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.repeat(df['ID'], lens),
                    'A': list(chain.from_iterable(A)),
                    'C': np.repeat(df['C'], lens)})

print(res)

#    A   C  ID
# 0  a   1   1
# 1  a   2   1
# 2  a  15   1
# 3  b   5   1
# 4  b  13   1
# 4  c  13   1
# 4  d  13   1
# 5  a   6   2
# 6  a   7   2
# 7  a   1   2
# 7  b   1   2
# 7  c   1   2
```

#### Step 2: Concatenate GroupBy on original and flattened

```
agg_df = pd.concat([res.groupby('ID')['A'].nunique(),
                    df.groupby('ID')['C'].sum()], axis=1)

print(agg_df)

#     A   C
# ID       
# 1   4  36
# 2   3  14
```

Comment: In my original problem there are many more columns (expect from 'A' and 'C') which I aggregate upon. How does this scale?

Comment: @EranMoshe, Depends on "many more", if it's < 10 columns this might scale fine. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51751138/convert-data-frame-to-another-data-frame-split-compound-string-cell-into-indivi/51751813#51751813) where you can use the same logic for arbitrary columns without typing out logic for each one separately. If you don't care about the intermediary result, then you can use the `apply(pd.Series)` + `stack` method