# concatenating columns in dataframe and generate new ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
City  hits
A     10
B     1
C     22
D     122
E     1
F     165
```

I want to make a dataframe with a single column called Hit_ID, whose rows are

```
A_1
A_2
etc.
A_10
B_1
C_1
C_2 
etc.
D_124
D_125
E_1
```

I tried 
`df['Hit_ID'] = df[['City','hits']].apply(lambda x:'_'.join(x.astype(str)),axis=1)` but this just concatenates the columns. How can I modify the apply function to get the desired op?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
#repeat index values by column hits
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['hits'])].reset_index(drop=True)
#create counts
df['hits'] = df.groupby('City').cumcount() + 1
#concatenate columns
df['Hit_ID'] = df['City'] + '_' + df['hits'].astype(str)
print (df.head(20))
   City  hits Hit_ID
0     A     1    A_1
1     A     2    A_2
2     A     3    A_3
3     A     4    A_4
4     A     5    A_5
5     A     6    A_6
6     A     7    A_7
7     A     8    A_8
8     A     9    A_9
9     A    10   A_10
10    B     1    B_1
11    C     1    C_1
12    C     2    C_2
13    C     3    C_3
14    C     4    C_4
15    C     5    C_5
16    C     6    C_6
17    C     7    C_7
18    C     8    C_8
19    C     9    C_9
```

Comment: This is not the desired output. The number of rows for City A should equal the number of Hits. i.e. the rows should be A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,A_5,A_6,A_7,A_8,A_9,A_10 and so on

Comment: Sorry, Idont understand it. Now solution was changed.

Comment: There is a tiny bug in this solution which actually doesn't give you the desired result. When you create the counter you should `groupby` by City not by hits. In the OP City *B* and *E* had the same number of hits which results in B_1 and E_2.
And for joining the strings you could also use `df['Hit_ID'] = df.astype(str).apply("_".join, axis=1)` Which is a bit shorter ;)

Comment: @Jan Zeiseweis thanks, solution was repaired. And your solution for joining is shorter, but slowier. Thank you for comment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['hits'] = df.hits.transform(lambda x: range(1, x))
s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['hits']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.name = 'hits'
df = pd.concat([df.City, s], axis=1)
df['hit_id'] = df.City + '_' + df.hits.astype(str)
```

- Change the `df.hits` from a column of integers to a column of lists, ranging from 1 to the original value.
- Use the technique discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list) by @RomanPekar to expand the column of lists into a series of rows.
- Concatenate that new column with the original `df.City` column.
- Join the two columns together with an `_`.