# Split Column containing lists into different rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas like this:

```
id     info
1      [1,2]
2      [3]
3      []
```

And I want to split it into different rows like this:

```
id     info
1      1 
1      2 
2      3 
3      NaN
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you definitely need the `NaN` entry there?

Comment: If it is possible, but I could ignore it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3], 'info': [[1,2],[3],[]]})
>>> s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['info']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
>>> s.name = 'info'
>>> df2 = df.drop('info', axis=1).join(s)
>>> df2['info'] = pd.Series(df2['info'], dtype=object)
>>> df2
   id info
0   1    1
0   1    2
1   2    3
2   3  NaN
```

Similar question is posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list)

Answer (score 1):

This is rather convoluted way, which drops empty cells:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3],
                   'info': [[1,2], [3], [ ]]})

unstack_df = df.set_index(['id'])['info'].apply(pd.Series)\
                                         .stack()\
                                         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

unstack_df = unstack_df.reset_index()
unstack_df.columns = ['id', 'info']

unstack_df

>>
       id   info
    0   1   1.0
    1   1   2.0
    2   2   3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `np.repeat` and `itertools.chain`. Converting empty lists to `{np.nan}` is a trick to fool Pandas into accepting an iterable as a value. This allows `chain.from_iterable` to work error-free.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

df.loc[~df['info'].apply(bool), 'info'] = {np.nan}

res = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df['id'], df['info'].map(len).values),
                    'info': list(chain.from_iterable(df['info']))})

print(res)

   id  info
0   1   1.0
0   1   2.0
1   2   3.0
2   3   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods too...

**Method 1**

```
def split_dataframe_rows(df,column_selectors):
    # we need to keep track of the ordering of the columns
    def _split_list_to_rows(row,row_accumulator,column_selector):
        split_rows = {}
        max_split = 0
        for column_selector in column_selectors:
            split_row = row[column_selector]
            split_rows[column_selector] = split_row
            if len(split_row) > max_split:
                max_split = len(split_row)

        for i in range(max_split):
            new_row = row.to_dict()
            for column_selector in column_selectors:
                try:
                    new_row[column_selector] = split_rows[column_selector].pop(0)
                except IndexError:
                    new_row[column_selector] = ''
            row_accumulator.append(new_row)

    new_rows = []
    df.apply(_split_list_to_rows,axis=1,args = (new_rows,column_selectors))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_rows, columns=df.columns)
    return new_df
```

**Method 2**

```
def flatten_data(json = None):
    df = pd.DataFrame(json)
    list_cols = [col for col in df.columns if type(df.loc[0, col]) == list]
    for i in range(len(list_cols)):
        col = list_cols[i]
        meta_cols = [col for col in df.columns if type(df.loc[0, col]) != list] + list_cols[i+1:]
        json_data = df.to_dict('records')
        df = json_normalize(data=json_data, record_path=col, meta=meta_cols, record_prefix=col+str('_'), sep='_')
    return json_normalize(df.to_dict('records'))
```