# pandas: When cell contents are lists/ NaN/ string, create a row for each element

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a df which similar below

```
index a  b  c  d
0     xx aa av NaN
1     pp as ka [1,2,3,4]
2     pa aj q  1234
3     xq aq aq NaN
4     pn an kn [10,20,30,40]
5     px ax kx "00012"
```

I would like to convert into some like below

```
index a  b  c  d              d-separated
0     xx aa av NaN            NaN
1     pp as ka [1,2,3,4]      1
2     pp as ka [1,2,3,4]      2
3     pp as ka [1,2,3,4]      3
4     pp as ka [1,2,3,4]      4
5     pa aj q  1234           1234
6     xq aq aq NaN            NaN
7     pn an kn [10,20,30,40]  10
8     pn an kn [10,20,30,40]  20
9     pn an kn [10,20,30,40]  30
10    pn an kn [10,20,30,40]  40
11    px ax kx "00012"        "00012"
```

I have take reference from

[pandas: When cell contents are lists, create a row for each element in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list) and

[Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/40449726#40449726)

However, as my case is different from them. The solution won't work in my example. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['xx', 'pp', 'pa', 'xq', 'pn', 'px'], 'b': ['aa', 'as', 'aj', 'aq', 'an', 'ax'], 'c': ['av', 'ka', 'q', 'aq', 'kn', 'kx'], 'd': [np.nan, [1,2,3,4], 1234, np.nan, [10, 20, 30, 40], '00012']})
```

This was a tricky one, mostly because of the `NaN`'s, so I replaced them with a filler value first, then changed them back at the end:

```
(df.join(df.fillna(-999)
    .d.apply(pd.Series))
    .drop('d', 1).set_index(['a', 'b', 'c'])
    .stack().reset_index()
    .drop('level_3',1)
    .replace(-999, np.nan).rename(columns={0: 'd-separated'})
)

     a   b   c d-separated
0   xx  aa  av         NaN
1   pp  as  ka           1
2   pp  as  ka           2
3   pp  as  ka           3
4   pp  as  ka           4
5   pa  aj   q        1234
6   xq  aq  aq         NaN
7   pn  an  kn          10
8   pn  an  kn          20
9   pn  an  kn          30
10  pn  an  kn          40
11  px  ax  kx       00012
```

This *does* however lose the original `d` column, since it contains unhashable types so it cannot be set as a level of the index.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not trivial - for column for index id necessary convert `list`s to `tuple`s for hashable types and for `DataFrame` from constructor scalar to one element `list`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['xx', 'pp', 'pa', 'xq', 'pn', 'px'], 
                   'b': ['aa', 'as', 'aj', 'aq', 'an', 'ax'], 
                   'c': ['av', 'ka', 'q', 'aq', 'kn', 'kx'], 
                   'd': [np.nan, [1,2,3,4], '1234', np.nan, [10, 20, 30, 40], '00012']})


s = (df.assign(d1=df['d'].fillna('NANval').apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x]),
               d = df['d'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x))
       .set_index(['a','b','c','d'])['d1']
       )
print (s)
a   b   c   d               
xx  aa  av  NaN                         [NANval]
pp  as  ka  (1, 2, 3, 4)            [1, 2, 3, 4]
pa  aj  q   1234                          [1234]
xq  aq  aq  NaN                         [NANval]
pn  an  kn  (10, 20, 30, 40)    [10, 20, 30, 40]
px  ax  kx  00012                        [00012]
Name: d1, dtype: object
```

---

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
        .stack()
        .reset_index(4, drop=True)
        .reset_index(name='d-separated')
        .replace('NANval', np.nan)
        )
```

Last if necessary convert `tuple`s to `list`s:

```
df['d'] = df['d'].apply(lambda x: list(x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x)
print (df)

     a   b   c                 d d-separated
0   xx  aa  av               NaN         NaN
1   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]           1
2   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]           2
3   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]           3
4   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]           4
5   pa  aj   q              1234        1234
6   xq  aq  aq               NaN         NaN
7   pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]          10
8   pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]          20
9   pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]          30
10  pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]          40
11  px  ax  kx             00012       00012
```

Answer (score 0):

First Expand the dataframe to the required size, repeating each row as necessary:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.index.repeat([len(x) if isinstance(x,list) else 1 for x in df.d])]
```

Now unlist the column d and concatenate it with the above df

```
d_sep= pd.DataFrame({'d_Sep':sum([x if isinstance(x,list) else [x] for x in df.d],[])})

df2 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True),d_sep],axis=1)

   a   b   c                 d  d_Sep
0   xx  aa  av               NaN    NaN
1   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]      1
2   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]      2
3   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]      3
4   pp  as  ka      [1, 2, 3, 4]      4
5   pa  aj   q              1234   1234
6   xq  aq  aq               NaN    NaN
7   pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]     10
8   pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]     20
9   pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]     30
10  pn  an  kn  [10, 20, 30, 40]     40
11  px  ax  kx             00012  00012
```

Comment: sorry, but it shows ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shape (768329,) (2,)