# How to find common elements in several dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A','M','C'],
                   'col2': ['B','N','O'],
                   # plus many more
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col3': ['A','A','A','B','B','B'],
                    'col4': ['M','P','Q','J','P','M'],
                   # plus many more
                   })
```

Which look like these:

**df1:**

```
col1   col2
A      B
M      N
C      O
#...plus many more
```

**df2:**

```
col3   col4
A      M
A      P
A      Q
B      J
B      P
B      M
#...plus many more
```

The objective is to create a dataframe containing all elements in `col4` for each `col3` that occurs in one row in `df1`. For example, let's look at row 1 of `df1`. We see that `A` is in `col1` and `B` is in `col2`. Then, we go to `df2`, and check what `col4` is for `df2[df2['col3'] == 'A']` and `df2[df2['col3'] == 'B']`. We get, for `A`: `['M','P','Q']`, and for `B`, `['J','P','M']`. The intersection of these is`['M', 'P']`, so what I want is something like this

```
col1   col2    col4
A      B       M
A      B       P
....(and so on for the other rows)
```

The naive way to go about this is to iterate over rows and then get the intersection, but I was wondering if it's possible to solve this via merging techniques or other faster methods. So far, I can't think of any way how.

Comment: Hi @ukemi, I added some details above. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you want, using a combination of `merge`, `groupby` and set intersection:

```
# Getting tuple of all col1=col3 values in col4
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='col1', right_on='col3')
df3 = df3.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col4'].apply(tuple)
df3 = df3.reset_index()

# Getting tuple of all col2=col3 values in col4
df3 = pd.merge(df3, df2, left_on='col2', right_on='col3')
df3 = df3.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col4_x'])['col4_y'].apply(tuple)
df3 = df3.reset_index()

# Taking set intersection of our two tuples
df3['col4'] = df3.apply(lambda row: set(row['col4_x']) & set(row['col4_y']), axis=1)

# Dropping unnecessary columns
df3 = df3.drop(['col4_x', 'col4_y'], axis=1)
```

```
print(df3)

  col1 col2    col4
0    A    B  {P, M}
```

If required, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list) for examples of how to 'melt' `col4`.