# How to Covert multiple list columns in data frame into given one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have Dataframe like this

```
     Number      String            Aut
  0 [12, 13]    [hi are, ho to]    ppppp
  1   34         How               qqqqq
  2   35         are               wwwwwww
```

i want to convert this into this

```
         Number      String            Aut
  0   12          hi are            ppppp
  1   13          ho to             ppppp
  2   34          How               qqqqq
  3   35          are               wwwwwww
```

i tried this but not working
 [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list)

```
res = df.set_index(['Aut'])['Number', 'String'].apply(pd.Series).stack()
```

Help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mix list with scalars, so first need some pre processing and then create DataFrame by `chain` with `repeat`:

```
n = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in df['Number']]
s = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in df['String']]
lens = [len(x) for x in n]

from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Number' : list(chain.from_iterable(n)), 
    'String' : list(chain.from_iterable(s)), 
    'Aut' : df['Aut'].values.repeat(lens)
})
print (df)
   Number  String      Aut
0      12  hi are    ppppp
1      13   ho to    ppppp
2      34     How    qqqqq
3      35     are  wwwwwww
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two steps:

```
step1_df=df.set_index('Aut').String.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'String'}) 

step2_df=df.set_index('Aut').Number.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'Number'})
```

Merge two df:

```
 final=pd.merge(step1_df,step2_df,on="Aut")
```