# Plot using seaborn with FacetGrid where values are ndarray in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn

I want to plot a dataframe where y values are stored as ndarrays within a column
i.e.:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0,4), columns=('sample','class','values'))
for iloc in [0,2]:
    df.loc[iloc] = {'sample':iloc, 
                    'class':'raw', 
                    'values':np.random.random(5)}
    df.loc[iloc+1] = {'sample':iloc,
                      'class':'predict',
                      'values':np.random.random(5)}

grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="class", row="sample")
grid.map(plt.plot, np.arange(0,5), "value")

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Do I need to break out the ndarrays into separate rows? Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite an unusual way of storing data in a dataframe. Two options (I'd recommend option B):

## A. Custom mapping in seaborn

Indeed seaborn does not support such format natively. You may construct your own function to plot to the grid though.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0,4), columns=('sample','class','values'))
for iloc in [0,2]:
    df.loc[iloc] = {'sample':iloc, 
                    'class':'raw', 
                    'values':np.random.random(5)}
    df.loc[iloc+1] = {'sample':iloc,
                      'class':'predict',
                      'values':np.random.random(5)}

grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="class", row="sample")

def plot(*args,**kwargs):
    plt.plot(args[0].iloc[0], **kwargs)

grid.map(plot, "values")
```

## B. Unnesting

However I would advise to "unnest" the dataframe first and get rid of the numpy arrays inside the cells.

[pandas: When cell contents are lists, create a row for each element in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list) shows a way to do that.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(0,4), columns=('sample','class','values'))
for iloc in [0,2]:
    df.loc[iloc] = {'sample':iloc, 
                    'class':'raw', 
                    'values':np.random.random(5)}
    df.loc[iloc+1] = {'sample':iloc,
                      'class':'predict',
                      'values':np.random.random(5)}

res = df.set_index(["sample", "class"])["values"].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
res.columns = ["sample", "class", "original_index", "values"]
```

[image]

Then use the `FacetGrid` in the usual way.

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(res, col="class", row="sample")
grid.map(plt.plot, "original_index", "values")
```

Comment: Thank you, great answer. I was working on the custom mapping function but realised the in-nesting approach was probably better. The apply stack solution is neat.