# Expand pandas dataframe on elements of list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one of the columns contains a list. I want to break up these lists so that each element has its own row.

Ex df:

```
index    Name              Color
  1      Ford    ['Red,Blue' , 'Red,Blue']
```

result df:

```
index    Name    Color
  1      Ford    Red
  2      Ford    Blue
  3      Ford    Red
  4      Ford    Blue
```

The code that I tried:

```
s = df['Color'].str.split(',').apply(Series,1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'Color'
del df['Color']
df = df.join(s)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: When cell contents are lists, create a row for each element in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list)

Comment: This is close, gets half way there. Full code below.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, answer below:

```
s = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Color']),axis=1).stack.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
s.Name = 'Color'
df = df.drop('Color', axis=1).join(s)

s = df['Color'].str.split(',').apply(Series,1).stack()
s.index = s.index.droplevel(-1)
s.name = 'Color'
del df['Color']
df = df.join(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `apply` on big data set is really slow. I come up with solution without using `apply` as follows: `set_index` on columns `index` and `Name`. Next, `join` and `split` on `Color`. Finally, create new datafrom from color list, then `stack` and `reset_index` and `drop` unwanted columns.

Using `df` as follows:

```
In [2370]: df
Out[2370]:
   index   Name                       Color
0      1   Ford        [Red,Blue, Red,Blue]
1      1  Chevy  [Yellow,Blue, Yellow,Blue]
2      1  Tesla     [White,Green, Red,Blue]


df.set_index(['index', 'Name'], inplace=True)
color_list = [','.join(st).split(',') for st in df.Color.tolist()]
pd.DataFrame(color_list, index=df.index).stack().reset_index(level=[1, 2]).drop('level_2', 1)

Out[2376]:
        Name       0
index
1       Ford     Red
1       Ford    Blue
1       Ford     Red
1       Ford    Blue
1      Chevy  Yellow
1      Chevy    Blue
1      Chevy  Yellow
1      Chevy    Blue
1      Tesla   White
1      Tesla   Green
1      Tesla     Red
1      Tesla    Blue
```

Comment: You need an extra step, since your example `df` does not match OP's. It should be created with something like `df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['Ford'], "Color": [["'Red,Blue'" , "'Red,Blue'"]]})`

Comment: @HS-nebula: base on his posted answer and the desired output, the additional single-quotes in the string is a typo. I tested his answer to check runtime with `%timeit` before I posted my answer. His answer provided output match his desired output only when there is no additional single-quotes.