# Generate row by values in two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I just joined [my first kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/recognizing-faces-in-the-wild/). I have a table like this:

```
| Person_id | Children_id | Person_Photos                      | Children_Photos        |
|-----------|-------------|------------------------------------|------------------------|
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_0.jpg, pid1_1.jpg, pid1_2.jpg | cid1_0.jpg, cid1_1.jpg |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_0.jpg, pid2_1.jpg, pid1_2.jpg | cid1_0.jpg, cid1_1.jpg |
```

I want to generate a row for each Person_Photos and Children_Photos match. E.g:

```
| Person_id | Children_id | Person_Photo | Children_Photo |
|-----------|-------------|--------------|----------------|
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_0.jpg   | cid1_0.jpg     |
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_0.jpg   | cid1_1.jpg     |
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_1.jpg   | cid1_0.jpg     |
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_1.jpg   | cid1_1.jpg     |
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_2.jpg   | cid1_0.jpg     |
| pid1      | cid1        | pid1_2.jpg   | cid1_1.jpg     |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_0.jpg   | cid1_0.jpg     |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_0.jpg   | cid1_1.jpg     |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_1.jpg   | cid1_0.jpg     |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_1.jpg   | cid1_1.jpg     |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_2.jpg   | cid1_0.jpg     |
| pid2      | cid1        | pid2_2.jpg   | cid1_1.jpg     |
```

How can i achieve this using pandas? Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list

Comment: @SimonRogers That answer only covers a single column. I have 2 columns with multiple values here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `Series` twice:

```py
one = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Person_Photos']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df = df.drop('Person_Photos', axis=1)
one.name = 'Person_Photos'
df = df.join(one)
two = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Children_Photos']), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
df = df.drop('Children_Photos', axis=1)
two.name = 'Children_Photos'
df = df.join(two)
```

Comment: running your code and then df.head(5) shows that the df hasn't changed at all. What am i missing here?

Comment: is your  pid1_0.jpg, pid1_1.jpg, pid1_2.jpg a list or an str?

Comment: it's a string currently

Comment: Fixed with: 

df['Person_Photos'] = df.Person_Photos.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(','))
df['Children_Photos'] = df.Children_Photos.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(','))

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'Person_id':['pid1','pid2'],
                  'Children_id':['cid1','cid1'],
                 'Person_Photos':["'pid1_0.jpg', 'pid1_1.jpg', 'pid1_2.jpg'","'pid2_0.jpg', 'pid2_1.jpg', 'pid1_2.jpg'"],
                 'Children_Photos':["'cid1_0.jpg', 'cid1_1.jpg'","'cid1_0.jpg', 'cid1_1.jpg'"]})


one=s.set_index('Person_id').Person_Photos.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index('Person_id')
one.columns=['Person_id','Person_Photos']
# print(one)
# print('*'*50)
two=s.set_index('Children_id').Children_Photos.str.split(',', expand=True).stack().reset_index('Children_id')
two.columns=['Children_id','Children_Photos']
# print(two)

one['tmp'] = 1
two['tmp'] = 1

pd.merge(one, two, on=['tmp'])
```

## Output

```
   Person_idPerson_Photos  tmp  Children_id Children_Photos
0   pid1    'pid1_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
1   pid1    'pid1_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
2   pid1    'pid1_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
3   pid1    'pid1_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
4   pid1    'pid1_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
5   pid1    'pid1_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
6   pid1    'pid1_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
7   pid1    'pid1_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
8   pid1    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
9   pid1    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
10  pid1    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
11  pid1    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
12  pid2    'pid2_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
13  pid2    'pid2_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
14  pid2    'pid2_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
15  pid2    'pid2_0.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
16  pid2    'pid2_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
17  pid2    'pid2_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
18  pid2    'pid2_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
19  pid2    'pid2_1.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
20  pid2    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
21  pid2    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
22  pid2    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_0.jpg'
23  pid2    'pid1_2.jpg'    1   cid1    'cid1_1.jpg'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! Unfortunately i get MemoryError: on line pd.merge(one, two, on=['tmp']). I have 16 GB but guess i need more... Any way i can optimize this?

Comment: can you share the total data size you have ? Number of columns and rows ?

Comment: 3362 rows and parents have up to 9 children, each children has up to 6 photos. it gets big real quick. I can share the csv if you'd like.