# How to deal with sublists and dataframe with pandas?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, list, nested-lists

My project is composed by several lists - that I put all together in a dataframe with pandas, to excel.
But one of my list contains sublists, and I don't know how to deal with that.

```
my_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
        "V1": list1,
        "V2": list2,
        "V3": list3
    })
my_dataframe.to_excel("test.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet 1", index=False, encoding='utf8')
```

Let's says that:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=['a','b','c']
list3=['d',['a','b','c'],'e']
```

I would like to end in my excel file file with:

[image]

I have really no idea how to proceed - if this is even possible?
Any help is welcomed :) Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the answer you are looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list), but then add the to excel part at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this before calling to_excel :

```
my_dataframe = (my_dataframe["V3"].apply(pd.Series)
.merge(my_dataframe.drop("V3", axis = 1), right_index = True, left_index = True)
.melt(id_vars = ['V1', 'V2'], value_name = "V3")
.drop("variable", axis = 1)
.dropna()
.sort_values("V1"))
```

credits to [Bartosz](https://mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-split-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-rows-in-pandas-9849d8ff2401)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is perfect!!

Comment: Hello cyrilb38
Do you know if we can do that with 2 lists containing sublists? I mean by that, if I take back my example, I have a list4=['1',['2','3','4'],'5'] and I want to do the same as with the list3. I've tried to use twice the code you put above, but this is not working, and I can't find the way to put 2 lists in the code you put above. Both lists have the same structure. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not generalizable. I would suggest to use the solution from MaxU : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449726/6081921.
Your first need to convert the lists you want to explode (list3 & list4) e.g. : list3 = [x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in list3]. Then use the explode function and that should do it

Comment: Thank you cyrilb38, I'll then try to work around to avoid this.