# How to split strings in R and place strings into specific columns based type?

Tags: r, string, split

I have a programming challenge that I can't overcome, please help! I have historical time series rates and dates stored as a string in one cell for each security (10K+ security). How can I split the string and store the information in their respective columns? I usually work in R but happy to try it in Python if easier!

Here is what my data looks like, "Security" and "Series" are my column names:

```
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+---+---+----+
| Security |              Series                                         | 
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+---+---+----+
| 567895B | "3/15/2019 2.51 3/17/2019 2.30 4/08/2019 2.41"               |
| 165456C | "1/05/2018 2.45 1/28/2018 2.46"                              |
| 123456A | "1/05/2016 2.45 2/05/2016 2.46 3/05/2016 2.45 5/05/2016 2.47"|
+----+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--+---+---+----+
```

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
+----+-------+-------+---------+------+
| Security   | date          |  rate  | 
+----+-------+-------+---------+------+
|  567895B   |   3/15/2019   |  2.51  |
|  567895B   |   3/17/2019   |  2.30  |
|  567895B   |   4/08/2019   |  2.41  |
|  165456C   |   1/05/2018   |  2.45  |      
|  165456C   |   1/28/2018   |  2.46  |
|  123456A   |   1/05/2016   |  2.45  |
|  123456A   |   2/05/2016   |  2.46  |   
|  123456A   |   3/05/2016   |  2.45  |   
|  123456A   |   5/05/2016   |  2.47  |   
+----+-------+-------+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can use `tidyverse` to do this. We first `separate` every values in `Series` into separate columns. To do that we calculate number of whitespaces in `Series` and select the maximum value so we know how many columns will be added. We then use `gather` to convert it into long form, create a group identifier for `Date` and `rate` field and cast it to wide format using `spread`.

```
library(tidyverse)
n <- max(str_count(df$Series, "\\s+")) + 1

df %>% 
  separate(Series, into = paste0("col", 1:n), sep = "\\s+", fill = "right") %>%
  gather(key, value, -Security, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(key = ceiling(as.integer(sub("col", "", key))/2)) %>%
  group_by(Security, key) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(row, value) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  rename_at(2:3, ~c("Date", "rate"))

# A tibble: 9 x 3
#  Security Date      rate
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>
#1 123456A  1/05/2016 2.45 
#2 123456A  2/05/2016 2.46 
#3 123456A  3/05/2016 2.45 
#4 123456A  5/05/2016 2.47 
#5 165456C  1/05/2018 2.45 
#6 165456C  1/28/2018 2.46 
#7 567895B  3/15/2019 2.51 
#8 567895B  3/17/2019 2.30 
#9 567895B  4/08/2019 2.41
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Security = c("567895B", "165456C", "123456A"), 
Series = c("3/15/2019 2.51 3/17/2019 2.30 4/08/2019 2.41", 
"1/05/2018 2.45 1/28/2018 2.46", "1/05/2016 2.45 2/05/2016 2.46 3/05/2016 
2.45 5/05/2016 2.47"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df%>%
   mutate(Series=strsplit(Series," (?=\\d+/)",perl = T))%>%
   unnest()%>%
   separate(Series,c('Date','Rate'),' ',convert = T)

  Security      Date Rate
1  567895B 3/15/2019 2.51
2  567895B 3/17/2019 2.30
3  567895B 4/08/2019 2.41
4  165456C 1/05/2018 2.45
5  165456C 1/28/2018 2.46
6  123456A 1/05/2016 2.45
7  123456A 2/05/2016 2.46
8  123456A 3/05/2016 2.45
9  123456A 5/05/2016 2.47
```

To use base R, you could do:

```
m = gregexpr("(^|\\s)(?=\\d+/)",df$Series,perl = T)
read.table(text=`regmatches<-`(df$Series, m ,val=paste("\n",df$Security,' ')))
       V1        V2   V3
1 567895B 3/15/2019 2.51
2 567895B 3/17/2019 2.30
3 567895B 4/08/2019 2.41
4 165456C 1/05/2018 2.45
5 165456C 1/28/2018 2.46
6 123456A 1/05/2016 2.45
7 123456A 2/05/2016 2.46
8 123456A 3/05/2016 2.45
9 123456A 5/05/2016 2.47
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the data frame `secs` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, insert a newline and the Security name before each date in the Series string.  The replacement character vector is defined as `repl`.  It is inserted into `Series` returning a character vector `ch` of the revised `Series`.  Then read `ch` in using `read.table` and finally change the date to `Date` class.  No packages are used.

```
repl <- sprintf("\n%s \\1", secs$Security)
ch <- mapply(gsub, "(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)", repl, secs$Series)
DF <- read.table(text = ch, col.names = c("Security", "Date", "Value"), as.is = TRUE)
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

giving:

```
> DF
  Security       Date Value
1  567895B 2019-03-15  2.51
2  567895B 2019-03-17  2.30
3  567895B 2019-04-08  2.41
4  165456C 2018-01-05  2.45
5  165456C 2018-01-28  2.46
6  123456A 2016-01-05  2.45
7  123456A 2016-02-05  2.46
8  123456A 2016-03-05  2.45
9  123456A 2016-05-05  2.47
```

The same code could alternately be written as the following pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)

secs %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ch = gsub("(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)", sprintf("\n%s \\1", Security), Series)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  { read.table(text = .$ch, col.names = c("Security", "Date", "Value"), as.is = TRUE) } %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- '
 Security |  Series
 567895B | "3/15/2019 2.51 3/17/2019 2.30 4/08/2019 2.41"               
 165456C | "1/05/2018 2.45 1/28/2018 2.46"                              
 123456A | "1/05/2016 2.45 2/05/2016 2.46 3/05/2016 2.45 5/05/2016 2.47" '
secs <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", na.strings = "+", 
  as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let see one way to do with the Python module `pandas`.
The steps:

1. Convert the column `Series` to a `list`.

   - Method used: `pandas.str.split`. [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
2. Define the columns `Security` as an index of the dataframe (usefull for the indexing in the next step).

   - Methods used: `set_index` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3. Convert the list in each rows as new lines. Inspired from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list).

   - Methods used:

     - `stack`: stack elements in the list of the rows
     - `reset_index`: [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
     - `to_frame`: [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)
4. Arange the new dataframe

Here the code of the different steps:

```
# Import module
import pandas as pd

# Define dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([["567895B" , "3/15/2019 2.51 3/17/2019 2.30 4/08/2019 2.41" ],
                    ["165456C" , "1/05/2018 2.45 1/28/2018 2.46" ],
                    ["123456A" , "1/05/2016 2.45 2/05/2016 2.46 3/05/2016 2.45 5/05/2016 2.47"]], 
                    columns = ["Security", "Series"])
print(df)
#   Security                                             Series
# 0  567895B       3/15/2019 2.51 3/17/2019 2.30 4/08/2019 2.41
# 1  165456C                      1/05/2018 2.45 1/28/2018 2.46
# 2  123456A  1/05/2016 2.45 2/05/2016 2.46 3/05/2016 2.45 5...

# Define indexation
df = df.set_index("Security")
print(df)
#                                                      Series
# Security
# 567895B        3/15/2019 2.51 3/17/2019 2.30 4/08/2019 2.41
# 165456C                       1/05/2018 2.45 1/28/2018 2.46
# 123456A   1/05/2016 2.45 2/05/2016 2.46 3/05/2016 2.45 5...

# Transform long string to list
df["Series"] = df["Series"].str.split(' ', expand=False)
print(df)
#                                                      Series
# Security
# 567895B   [3/15/2019, 2.51, 3/17/2019, 2.30, 4/08/2019, ...
# 165456C                  [1/05/2018, 2.45, 1/28/2018, 2.46]
# 123456A   [1/05/2016, 2.45, 2/05/2016, 2.46, 3/05/2016, ...

# Transform list in new rows
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['Series']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame()
df.columns = ["Series"]
print(df)
#              Series
# Security
# 567895B   3/15/2019
# 567895B        2.51
# 567895B   3/17/2019
# 567895B        2.30
# 567895B   4/08/2019
# 567895B        2.41
# 165456C   1/05/2018
# 165456C        2.45
# 165456C   1/28/2018
# 165456C        2.46
# 123456A   1/05/2016
# 123456A        2.45
# 123456A   2/05/2016
# 123456A        2.46
# 123456A   3/05/2016
# 123456A        2.45
# 123456A   5/05/2016
# 123456A        2.47

# Rebuild dataset
res = pd.DataFrame({"Date": df["Series"][::2], 
                    "Rate": df["Series"][1::2]})
print(res)
#                Date  Rate
# Security
# 567895B   3/15/2019  2.51
# 567895B   3/17/2019  2.30
# 567895B   4/08/2019  2.41
# 165456C   1/05/2018  2.45
# 165456C   1/28/2018  2.46
# 123456A   1/05/2016  2.45
# 123456A   2/05/2016  2.46
# 123456A   3/05/2016  2.45
# 123456A   5/05/2016  2.47
```

Answer (score 0):

And for an old-fashioned method in base R (without argument checks):

```
# Starting with values in `df`
  txt <- strsplit(df$Series, "\\s+")
  Security <- rep(df$Security, lengths(txt)/2) # note 'lengths' with 's'
  txt <- unlist(txt)
  date <- txt[seq(1, length(txt), 2)] # here just 'length'
  rate <- txt[seq(2, length(txt), 2)]
  ans <- data.frame(Security, date, rate)
```