# Pandas idiomatic way to do this custom duplicating rows function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got a pd.DataFrame, with each line representing a group of people. They have got an id (several columns in my dataframe, but here summarized by the `"id"` column of my example dataframe). Each of this group represent several people (column `"size"`).

I am trying to divide theses groups into smaller groups of a maximal size `"max_size"`. For example, if `max_size = 5`a row with `"id" = "foo"` and `"size" = 13` should be replaced by three rows, all with `"id" = "foo"` and respective `"size" = 5`, `"size" = 5`, and `"size" = 3`

I have coded an usable function, but am looking for a **more pandas idiomatic way** to do it, if it exists.

my function is

```py
def custom_duplicating_function(df):
    def aux_custom_duplicating_function(row, max_size=5):
        row = row.to_dict()
        size = row["size"]
        L = [row.copy() for i in range((size // max_size + 1))]
        for i in range(len(L) - 1):
            L[i]["size"] = max_size 
        L[-1]["size"] = size%max_size
        return(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(L))

    temp = df.apply(aux_custom_duplicating_function, axis=1)
    result = pd.concat([temp[i] for i in range(len(temp.index))])
    return(result)
```

The following dataframe

```
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{"id":"foo", "size":13},
                     {"id":"bar", "size":17},
                     {"id":"baz", "size":3}])
************
    id  size
0  foo    13
1  bar    17
2  baz     3
************
```

should be transformed in

```
    id  size
0  foo     5
1  foo     5
2  foo     3
0  bar     5
1  bar     5
2  bar     5
3  bar     2
0  baz     3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `explode` for pandas >=0.25

```
test['size'] = test['size'].apply(lambda x:[5]*(x//5)+[(x%5)])

test.explode('size')
```

Comment: i like this answer, clever .. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

We could nest the items via `apply` and then unnest them using e.g. the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element).

```
import pandas as pd
max_size=5
test = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{"id":"foo", "size":13},
                     {"id":"bar", "size":17},
                     {"id":"baz", "size":3}])

test['size'] = test['size'].apply(lambda x: [max_size]*(x//max_size)+[x%max_size])
test2 = test.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x['size']),axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
test2.name = 'size'
test.drop('size', axis=1).join(test2)

    id  size
0  foo   5.0
0  foo   5.0
0  foo   3.0
1  bar   5.0
1  bar   5.0
1  bar   5.0
1  bar   2.0
2  baz   3.0
```