# Reformat dataframe using pandas by adding new rows based on dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas

Given below is my dataframe

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['1','2'],'Col2':[{'a':['a1','a2']},{'b':['b1']}]})`

```
    Col1    Col2
0   1       {u'a': [u'a1', u'a2']}
1   2       {u'b': [u'b1']}
```

I need to reformat this data frame as below

```
   Col1     NCol2   NCol3
0   1         a     a1
1   1         a     a2
2   2         b     b1
```

Basically, for each key value pair in the dictionary, i am adding a row with key and value in Ncol2 and Ncol3.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: How did you get this dataframe in that format in the first place? It might make more sense  to fix the process of creating it rather than trying to transform if after the fact.

Comment: Even i would have prefered it that way, but this is how i got my dataset

Comment: Please refer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element/48532692#48532692 Looks like a  nice solution up there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
df1 = df['Col2'].apply(pd.Series).apply(lambda x: x.explode())\
.stack().reset_index(level=1)

df1.columns = ['Col2', 'Col3']

df.drop('Col2', axis=1).merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)\
.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3
0    1    a   a1
1    1    a   a2
2    2    b   b1
```

Comment: `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'", 'occurred at index a')`

Comment: @Dan Need to update your Pandas. It's new in Pandas 0.25.0.

Comment: Got another solution without using explode. This is from answer for question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element/48532692#48532692


                                                                                                                       ```lst_col = 'attr_list'
df_new = pd.DataFrame({
      col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[lst_col].str.len())
      for col in df.columns.drop(lst_col)}
    ).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(df[lst_col].values)})[df.columns]```