# Nested dictionary of lists to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
 {'a': {'col_1': [1, 2], 'col_2': ['a', 'b']},
 'b': {'col_1': [3, 4], 'col_2': ['c', 'd']}}
```

When I try to convert this to a dataframe a get this:

```
     col_1  col_2
a   [1, 2]  [a, b]
b   [3, 4]  [c, d]
```

But what I need is this:

```
     col_1  col_2
a      1      a
       2      b
b      3      c
       4      d
```

How can I get this format. Maybe I should change my input format as well? 
Thanks for help=)

Comment: _Maybe I should change my input format as well?_ By that do you mean modify the data before creating the DataFrame, or modify the source of the data itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas column of lists, create a row for each list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) setting `orient='index'` so the dictionary keys are set as the dataframe's indices, and then explode all columns by applying [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').apply(pd.Series.explode)

  col_1 col_2
a     1     a
a     2     b
b     3     c
b     4     d
```

Answer (score 1):

you could run a [generator comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) and apply pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) ... the comprehension works on the values of the dictionary, which are themselves dictionaries :

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(entry).assign(key=key) for key,entry in data.items()).set_index('key')

    
    col_1   col_2
key     
a    1       a
a    2       b
b    3       c
b    4       d
```

**update**:

Still uses concatenation; no need to assign `key` to individual dataframes:

```
 (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(entry) 
             for key, entry in data.items()], 
             keys=data)
  .droplevel(-1))
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest answer here, I'd have to set up a benchmark test but this seems among the fastest as well.