# Pandas explode a list column, but with extra column, which notes the position in the list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Similar to this question: [Pandas column of lists, create a row for each list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element)

I want to `explode` a list column, but also get a rank column. None of the answers given in the above question is really doing the job.

So, here is how my data frame looks like:

```
 df =
         a                     b     

         1                    [2, 4, 6]
         2                    [1, 5, 8, 10]

         ...                   ...
```

`b` is a list column.

Here is what I want:

```
df = 
       a                       b                 rank 
       1                       2                  1
       1                       4                  2
       1                       6                  3
       2                       1                  1
       2                       5                  2
       2                       8                  3
       2                       10                 4
      ...                      ...                ...
```

Notice, the `rank` column. `rank` says the rank of the respective element in the column `b`. It could also start with `0` index. But, it needs to be there.

Here is what I tried, taking the answer from the question cited:

```
      res = df.set_index(['a'])['b'].apply(pd.Series).stack()
```

Now, the above solution would have worked if `b` was an equal sized list on all rows. But, it isn't. `explode` would have worked if I did not need the `rank` column.

So, how to do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
newdf = df.explode('b')
newdf['rank'] = newdf.groupby('a').cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['rank']=df.explode('b').groupby('a')['b'].cumcount()+1
```

Comment: I am little confused by the assign ~ after explode

Comment: @BEN_YO Which sign?

Comment: df.explode('b').groupby('a')['b'].cumcount()+1 and you assign back to the original dataframe

Comment: @wwnde, was taking a lot of time for me, not sure, why.