# Reverse the group/items in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a table like this:

| Group | Item |
| --- | --- |
| A | a, b, c |
| B | b, c, d |

And I want to convert to like this:

| Item | Group |
| --- | --- |
| a | A |
| b | A, B |
| c | A, B |
| d | B |

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Would you like to share what's you've tried, and where do you get stuck?

Comment: How is your table stored? Show some example code!

Comment: As others have said, post some code. What have you tried? Is this a `pandas` dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working in pandas, you can use 'explode' to unpack items, and can use 'to_list' lambda for the grouping stage.

Here is some info on 'explode' method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Group': ['A', 'B'], 'Item': [['a','b','c'], ['b','c','d']]})
```

**Exploding**

```
df.explode('Item').reset_index(drop=True).to_dict(orient='records')
[{'Group': 'A', 'Item': 'a'},
 {'Group': 'A', 'Item': 'b'},
 {'Group': 'A', 'Item': 'c'},
 {'Group': 'B', 'Item': 'b'},
 {'Group': 'B', 'Item': 'c'},
 {'Group': 'B', 'Item': 'd'}]
```

**Exploding and then using 'to_list' lambda**

```
df.explode('Item').groupby('Item')['Group'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
[{'Item': 'a', 'Group': ['A']},
 {'Item': 'b', 'Group': ['A', 'B']},
 {'Item': 'c', 'Group': ['A', 'B']},
 {'Item': 'd', 'Group': ['B']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient, but very short:

```
>>> table = {'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['b', 'c', 'd']}
>>> reversed_table = {v: [k for k, vs in table.items() if v in vs] for v in set(v for vs in table.values() for v in vs)}
>>> print(reversed_table)
{'b': ['A', 'B'], 'c': ['A', 'B'], 'd': ['B'], 'a': ['A']}
```

Answer (score 0):

With dictionaries, you wouldtypically approach it like this:

```
table = {'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': ['b', 'c', 'd']}

revtable = dict()
for v,keys in table.items():
    for k in keys:
        revtable.setdefault(k,[]).append(v)

print(revtable)
# {'a': ['A'], 'b': ['A', 'B'], 'c': ['A', 'B'], 'd': ['B']}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your tables are in the form of a pandas dataframe, you could try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create initial dataframe
data = {'Group': ['A', 'B'], 'Item': [['a','b','c'], ['b','c','d']]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

    Group   Item
0   A   [a, b, c]
1   B   [b, c, d]
```

```
# Expand number of rows based on list column ("Item") contents
list_col = 'Item'
df = pd.DataFrame({
      col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[list_col].str.len())
      for col in df.columns.drop(list_col)}
    ).assign(**{list_col:np.concatenate(df[list_col].values)})[df.columns]

    Group   Item
0   A       a
1   A       b
2   A       c
3   B       b
4   B       c
5   B       d
```

*Above snippet taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element), which includes a more detailed explanation of the code

```
# Perform groupby operation 
df = df.groupby('Item')['Group'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Group')

    Item    Group
0   a     [A]
1   b     [A, B]
2   c     [A, B]
3   d     [B]
```