# Filter rows with more than 1 value in a set and count their occurrence pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume, I have the following data frame.

```
Id   Combinations
1      (A,B)
2      (C,)
3      (A,D)
4      (D,E,F)
5      (F)
```

I would like to filter out `Combination` column values with more than value in a set. Something like below. AND I would like count the number of occurrence as whole in `Combination` column. For example, `ID` number `2` and `5` should be removed since their value in a set is only 1.

The result I am looking for is:

```
ID     Combination     Frequency
1        A                2               
1        B                1
3        A                2
3        D                2
4        D                2
4        E                1
4        F                2
```

Can anyone help to get the above result in Python pandas?

Comment: What did you try until now ? Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if necessary convert values to lists:

```
df['Combinations'] = df['Combinations'].str.strip('(,)').str.split(',')
```

If need count after filtering only one values by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and count values by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df1 = df[df['Combinations'].str.len().gt(1)].explode('Combinations')
df1['Frequency'] = df1['Combinations'].map(df1['Combinations'].value_counts())
print (df1)
   Id Combinations  Frequency
0   1            A          2
0   1            B          1
2   3            A          2
2   3            D          2
3   4            D          2
3   4            E          1
3   4            F          1
```

Or if need count before removing them filter them by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) in last step:

```
df2 = df.explode('Combinations')
df2['Frequency'] = df2['Combinations'].map(df2['Combinations'].value_counts())

df2 = df2[df2['Id'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Alternative:

```
df2 = df2[df2.groupby('Id').Id.transform('size') > 1]
```

Or:

```
df2 = df2[df2['Id'].map(df2['Id'].value_counts() > 1]
```

---

```
print (df2)
   Id Combinations  Frequency
0   1            A          2
0   1            B          1
2   3            A          2
2   3            D          2
3   4            D          2
3   4            E          1
3   4            F          2
```

Comment: the solution that I am looking for is exactly your second solution. But when I tried it, I am getting empty data frame. Can you check it once again, please?

Comment: @Hiwot - What is `print (df['Combinations'].head().tolist())` of your input data?

Comment: Yes, I can see the result--> ```['(A,B)', '(C,)', '(A,D)', '(D,E,F)', '(F,)']```

Comment: @Hiwot - So you use `df['Combinations'] = df['Combinations'].str.strip('(,)').str.split(',')` in first step?

Comment: I used ```df['Combinations'] = df['Combinations'].str.strip('(,)').str.split(',')``` then put the second solution after that. I got this error: ```ValueError: keep must be either "first", "last" or False``` To solve this, I added ```df.drop_duplicates(['Id'],keep='first')``` but same.

Comment: I solved it by replacing ```df = df[df['Id'].duplicated(keep=False)]``` with ```df = df[df_sample.groupby('Id').Id.transform(len) > 1]```

Comment: @Hiwot - super, or fatser alternative, very similar is `df = df[df.groupby('Id').Id.transform('size') > 1] `

Comment: @Hiwot - I rename solutions for `df1` and `df2`.