# Convert elements of a list in Dataframe to a column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as below:

```
                                 2021-02-01 00:00:00
0  [0.22081292351898762, 0.22248217707309176, 0.2...
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
   2021-02-01 00:00:00
0  0.22081292351898762
1  0.22248217707309176
2  0.2...
3  00000
```

Please give me some advises. Thank you.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [] //your list
Use df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Comment: Don't name your variables `list`, because it can shadow the built-in type `list`.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

```
data = {'my_column': [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
   my_column
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [4, 5, 6]
```

Use `explode`:

```
df_explode = df.explode('my_column', ignore_index=True)
print(df_explode)
  my_column
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         6
```