# Create a new df from two columns where one of them contains multiple values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

i have a df that contains some columns like the following table.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1,3,5 | id_1 |
| b | 2,5,7 | id_2 |
| c | 8,13,18 | id_3 |

What I want is to extract the values from Column B into a new df with the Values from column C like this:

| id_col | val_col |
| --- | --- |
| id_1 | 1 |
| id_1 | 3 |
| id_1 | 5 |
| id_2 | 2 |
| id_2 | 5 |
| id_2 | 7 |
| id_3 | 8 |
| id_3 | 13 |
| id_3 | 18 |

Maybe my search terms are not specific enough, cause its not my native language, but I just don't found a solution yet.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I think the second answer here, using df.explode(), should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element

Comment: THANKS!! That was exactly I was looking for. Have a great weekend. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think this work for your problem:

```
import pandas as pd

data={
    'A': ['a', 'b','c'],
    'B': [[1,3,5], [2,5,7],[8,13,18]],
    'C':['id_1','id_2','id_3']
     }
data_frame=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df_result=data_frame.apply(lambda r: pd.Series({'id_col':r['C'],
                                      'val_col':r['B'],
                                     }),axis=1).explode('val_col')
print(df_result)
```

Comment: Thanks. The topic linked by Leo solved my problem. Also just "df_result = data_frame.explode()" worked fine.

Comment: I just know this,but  I went to create new Dataframe like that you want. I wish you best,

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this:

```
df.assign(B=df['B'].str.split(',')).explode('B')[['B', 'C']]
```

Output:

```
    B     C
0   1  id_1
0   3  id_1
0   5  id_1
1   2  id_2
1   5  id_2
1   7  id_2
2   8  id_3
2  13  id_3
2  18  id_3
```