# Extract value list into a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe looks like

| ID | fields |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [egg, apple, toy..] |
| 2 | [orange, bear, red..] |

with lists on fields

and I wish to output a separate datadrame for each ID, so the number of dataframe would be the number of rows and the output would look like this for the first dataframe

| Value |
| --- |
| egg |
| apple |
| toy |

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas column of lists, create a row for each list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-column-of-lists-create-a-row-for-each-list-element)

Comment: This can be done using the `explode` method for  [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html#pandas.DataFrame.explode) or [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html?highlight=explode#pandas.Series.explode), eg `df.explode('fields')` or `df['fields'].explode()`

Comment: How are you going to call all these dataframes? Do you want a list of dataframes? Do you want to store them in a dictionary (maybe using the index as keys)?

Comment: Do you know how to create a DataFrame using a list?

Answer (score 1):

I'd approach it like this, but would probably avoid storing lists of data in cells to begin vith, better to have data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) as it makes various pandas functionality a lot easier to work with. Not sure of the use case of many dataframes either, normally we'd have one dataframe and use e.g. groupby to access by ID.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1, 2], "fields": [["eggs", "apple", "toy"], ["orange", "bear", "red"]]})

df = df.explode("fields")
dataframes = []
for f_id in df["ID"].unique():
    df_id = df.loc[df["ID"] == f_id]
    dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(df_id).drop(columns='ID'))
```

Comment: You're right that list cells are not ideal. However, you're basically re-inventing `explode`, just slower and less concise. As a rule of thumb, looping over a dataframe is almost always wrong.

Comment: Fair comment -  the lists in cells and use case of many dataframe is a bit of an odd one. I've edited the answer above to use explode.