# Finding a Shared Motif

Tags: python

I need help with one problem in Rosalind here is the link to the problem for more information: http://rosalind.info/problems/lcsm/

The following is the sample input:

```
>Rosalind_1
GATTACA
>Rosalind_2
TAGACCA
>Rosalind_3
ATACA
```

Sample output is :

```
AC
```

and that's the basic information of the input and output:

> ```
> Given:  A collection of k (k≤100) DNA strings of length at most
>         1 kbp each in FASTA format.
>
> Return: A longest common substring of the collection. (If multiple
>         solutions exist, you may return any single solution.)
> ```

The problem is asking to find the longest shared string that is present in all three sequences, and the common longest string found in this example is `AC`.

Now, moving to the issue with programming it.

The idea I had - and tried - is to take the first string `GATTACA` and check all the combination of symbols and check if it is present in the sequence two and three.

How can I do that to loop over all possible bases for all the three sequences and find the longest motif in python?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem in computer science and in Bioinformatics. It is often referred to as the Longest common substring (LCS) problem. In your case this is extended to LCS for >2 sequences.

A technique called "Dynamic programming" is often used for LCS for two sequences and can be extended for >2. Dynamic programming as breaking down a problem into subproblems, solving (and remebering the answers) to the subproblems and finally tracing back to get the answer to the full problem. Another approach is to use [a general suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Suffix_tree).

I suggest you first look at how this is solved for 2 strings: [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring).

Then see how it can be extended for >2. This previous question also seems to be very [relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python) and has associated code.

Good luck!