# Check if a string contains another

Tags: python, pattern-matching

Checking if a string contains another, why does the first case turn False?

```
's161_1189a' in 's161_1189b'
```

False

```
's160_1156' in '159:s160_1156'
```

True

Comment: because 's161_1189a' in 's161_1189b' are different, one is ending with a and other with b

Comment: but 's160_1156'  and '159:s160_1156' are also different

Comment: because in 2nd case, 's160_1156' is subset of '159:s160_1156', thus it will give True

Comment: The `in` operator on two strings means: is the left argument text contained in the right argument text, exactly, fully and case sensitive.

Comment: Some of 's161_1189a' is in 's161_1189b', but *not* all of 's161_1189a' is in 's161_1189b'

Comment: In fact, if you actually want the longest common substring this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` operator is used to test if a sequence (list, tuple, string etc.) contains a value. It returns True if the value is present, else it returns False. For example

```
>>> x = 'subset'
>>>'sub' in x
True
>>>'subsets' in x
False

>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> 5 in a
True
>>> 10 in a
False
```