# Finding *modal* substring of a list of strings in python

Tags: python, string, list, longest-substring

Finding a *common* substring has been answered in many questions, i.e. given a list of strings find the (typically longest or largest number of words) substring that is common to *all* of them. See here:

[Longest common substring from more than two strings - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings-python/2894073#2894073)

My question is, how does one go about finding the longest *modal* substring in a list of strings? The important stipulation here is that this substring does not necessarily have to appear in all strings in the list.

There is a little bit of art to the science here because the obvious tradeoff is between 1) how many strings do you want the substring to appear in? and 2) how long do you want the substring to be? To fix ideas, lets just assume that we want the desired substring to have three words (in case of a tie here, take the longest string, followed by first instance).

So given the list,

```
mylist = ["hey how's it going?", "I'm fine  thanks.", "Did you get that thing?", "Of course I got that thing, that's why I asked you: how's it going?"]
```

The desired output is,

```
"how's it going"
```

If the stipulation was instead two words long then the desired output would be,

```
"that thing"
```

Since "that thing" is a longer string than, "how's it" or "it going"

The above answers in code are the modal substrings of three and two words long, respectively.

---

EDIT:

Since there is a bounty on this I will be a little more specific with what a modal sub-string is.

*Modal substring*: For a given length of words in the substring (this is needed to uniquely identify the modal substring), the modal substring is the substring that is common to the largest number of strings in the list. If there is a tie (i.e. for a given length of three words in the substring there are two candidate substrings that both appear in 80% of the strings) then the substring with the longest character length should be used. If there is a still a tie after that (which should be very unlikely but is good to account for), then just take the first one or choose randomly.

---

A *good* answer would have a function that returns the modal substring for a given number of words in the substring (where the number of words can be an arbitrary number).

An *incredible* answer would dispense with the 'given number of words' restriction and instead include a scalar (say \alpha) that manages the tradeoff between substring length (in words) and number of times it appears in the list. Alpha close to 1 would choose a modal substring that is very long (in words) but doesn't necessarily appear many times in the list. Alpha close to 0 would choose a modal substring that appears in as many times in the list as possible and doesn't care about substring length. I am not really expecting this though and will accept an answer that answers the original question.

Comment: Sorry, can you give the definition of a "modal substring"? Top google hit for me is your own question

Comment: Sure. Will edit the post.

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote? This is a well formulated question which could be relevant to many people. I also put up my own rep for the bounty. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I'm glad you asked this question - you've framed exactly the problem I'm looking to solve. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Finding modal substring of given length

Our input is as follows:

```
mylist = ["hey how's it going?", "I'm fine  thanks.", "Did you get that thing?", "Of course I got that thing, that's why I asked you: how's it going?"]
```

First, we'll define a preprocessing function, to clean up extra white spaces and punctuation. This makes it easier to extract words from the sentences:

```
def preprocess(strings):
    # used this answer to get rid of extra whitespaces: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546251/6735980
    return [" ".join(string.split()).replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("?", "") for string in strings]
```

We'll also define a helper function to find *n*-grams (substrings of *n* words in a sentence):

```
def find_n_grams(string, n):
    words = string.split(" ")
    n_grams = []

    for i in range(len(words) - n + 1):
        n_grams.append(" ".join([words[i + idx] for idx in range(n)]))

    return n_grams
```

Then, we can use the following function to find a "modal substring" as defined in the question, for a given number of words. I am not sure if this is the most optimal/efficient way to compute it, but it does the job:

```
def find_modal_substring(strings, num_words):
    n_grams_per_string = [find_n_grams(string, num_words) for string in strings]
    max_num_occurences = 0
    modal_substring = None

    for i in range(len(strings)):
        n_grams = n_grams_per_string[i]

        for n_gram in n_grams:
            num_occurences = 1

            for j in range(i + 1, len(strings)):
                if n_gram in n_grams_per_string[j]:
                    num_occurences += 1

            if num_occurences > max_num_occurences:
                max_num_occurences = num_occurences
                modal_substring = n_gram
            elif num_occurences == max_num_occurences and len(modal_substring) < len(n_gram):
                max_num_occurences = num_occurences
                modal_substring = n_gram

    return modal_substring
```

Some input/output pairs:

```
> print(find_modal_substring(preprocess(mylist), 3))
```

> how's it going

```
> print(find_modal_substring(preprocess(mylist), 2))
```

> that thing

---

#### Finding modal substring with alpha parameter

The most difficult thing in this part of the question is how to define a score function given the alpha parameter. We know that:

> Alpha close to 1 would choose a modal substring that is very long (in words) but doesn't necessarily appear many times in the list. Alpha close to 0 would choose a modal substring that appears in as many times in the list as possible and doesn't care about substring length.

One score function that satisfies this is the following, but we can probably think of many others as well. By isolating it in a function, anyone can easily modify it to their needs:

```
def compute_score(n_gram, occurences, alpha):
    return alpha * len(n_gram.split(" ")) + (1.0 - alpha) * occurences
```

Given that, the function to find an alpha-based modal substring is rather long because it first needs to find all possible *n*-grams for all *n*, but here we go:

```
def find_modal_substring_alpha(strings, alpha):
    n_grams_per_n_per_string = []
    n = 1

    while True:
        n_grams_per_string = [find_n_grams(string, n) for string in strings]

        if all(n_grams == [] for n_grams in n_grams_per_string):
            break
        else:
            n_grams_per_n_per_string.append(n_grams_per_string)

        n += 1

    best_modal_substring = None
    best_score = 0.0

    for n_grams_per_string in n_grams_per_n_per_string:
        for i in range(len(strings)):
            n_grams = n_grams_per_string[i]

            for n_gram in n_grams:
                num_occurences = 1

                for j in range(i + 1, len(strings)):
                    if n_gram in n_grams_per_string[j]:
                        num_occurences += 1

                score = compute_score(n_gram, num_occurences, alpha)

                if score > best_score:
                    best_score = score
                    best_modal_substring = n_gram
                elif score == best_score and len(best_modal_substring) < len(n_gram):
                    best_score = score
                    best_modal_substring = n_gram

    return best_modal_substring
```

It turns out that alpha is a bit difficult to tune here. Even for a relatively low alpha (`0.3`), we get exactly the same as we would get for `1.0`:

```
> print(find_modal_substring_alpha(preprocess(mylist), 0.3))
```

> Of course I got that thing that's why I asked you: how's it going

If we move alpha all the way down to `0.01` for example, we get:

```
> print(find_modal_substring_alpha(preprocess(mylist), 0.01))
```

> how's it going

Comment: This looks great! Thanks for doing the extension with the alpha parameter too!

Comment: This is a good solution. In an ideal world, we could dispense with alpha altogether by looking for the alpha that maximises the _total match_ (i.e. `length_of_string * count_of_occurrences`).