# Creating a glob programmatically; reverse glob; str[] -> glob

Tags: python, glob

How do I create a maximal glob from a list of strings?

Input:

```
['onething.txt', 'anotherthing.txt']
```

Output:

```
*o*thing.txt
```

or

```
*thing.txt
```

Whichever is more correct.

Comment: This sounds very similar to the [longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) to me, so maybe using one of algorithms for solving would help (or finding a modules that does).

Comment: What exactly do you consider "maximal" or "more correct"?  `[oa]n*e*thing.txt` is the most specific pattern I can come up with given the limitations of globs, but that still matches lots of potential filenames other than the two inputs.

Comment: For this situation I'm not too picky. Something like `*n*e*thing.txt` would be fine. It looks like `difflib` has some utilities to handle this. I would prefer more than one matching substring segment (not only the longest match; in this case thing.txt)

Comment: `os.path.commonprefix` is cool. I didn't know that existed. That might be good enough for my situation actually...

Comment: I think I'll go ahead and close this question because there are many answers already. I just wasn't searching google for "common substring"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715688/find-common-substring-between-two-strings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892931/longest-common-substring-from-more-than-two-strings